# Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'hlv_listViewStyle'

Tags: android, resources, styles

I have to use **Horizontal list-view library** in my android code when I am creating a demo app of Horizontal list-view Library it is throwing error.

> **No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'hlv_listViewStyle'.**

Platform:4.4.2

API Level:19

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

res\values\styles.xml:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="hlv_listViewStyle">@style/HListView</item>
        <item name="hlv_absHListViewStyle">@style/AbsHListView</item>
        <item name="hlv_listPreferredItemWidth">64dip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AbsHListView">
        <item name="android:scrollbars">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HListView" parent="AbsHListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">?android:attr/colorBackgroundCacheHint</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright</item>
        <item name="android:scrollingCache">false</item>
        <item name="android:overScrollMode">always</item>
        <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:smoothScrollbar">false</item>
        <item name="android:choiceMode">multipleChoiceModal</item>
        <item name="hlv_stackFromRight">false</item>
        <item name="hlv_measureWithChild">0</item>
        <item name="hlv_dividerWidth">3dip</item>
        <item name="hlv_headerDividersEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="hlv_footerDividersEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="hlv_transcriptMode">disabled</item>
    </style>
```

I am an android newbie.Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are missing the attribute **hlv_listViewStyle**. The style is there, but the reference linking it with the theme might not be. Check in your attr.xml file (if it exists, else create it under values folder) that you have the following:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="hlv_listViewStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same issue and adding the following like to my build.gradle fixed it:

```
compile project(':library')
// where "library" was the name of my HorizontalVariableListView library
```

Also make sure that your styles.xml looks [like that of the demo](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/blob/master/demo/res/values/styles.xml):

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
>     <item name="hlv_listViewStyle">@style/HListView</item>
>     <item name="hlv_absHListViewStyle">@style/AbsHListView</item>
>     <item name="hlv_listPreferredItemWidth">64dip</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="AbsHListView">
>     <item name="android:scrollbars">horizontal</item>
>     <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="HListView" parent="AbsHListView">
>     <item name="android:listSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
>     <item name="android:cacheColorHint">?android:attr/colorBackgroundCacheHint</item>
>     <item name="android:divider">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright</item>
>     <item name="android:scrollingCache">false</item>
>     <item name="android:overScrollMode">always</item>
>     <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
>     <item name="android:smoothScrollbar">false</item>
>     <item name="android:choiceMode">multipleChoiceModal</item>
>     <item name="hlv_stackFromRight">false</item>
>     <item name="hlv_measureWithChild">0</item>
>     <item name="hlv_dividerWidth">3dip</item>
>     <item name="hlv_headerDividersEnabled">true</item>
>     <item name="hlv_footerDividersEnabled">true</item>
>     <item name="hlv_transcriptMode">disabled</item>
> </style>
> ```